# Appcelerator Titanium Multi-select Picker Android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, picker

Is there any way to create a picker which allows you to select multiple rows? Or something that is similar to this (Something that looks like when you select multiple files in a File Browser)?

Answer (score 2):

Try This Code, This code is from Appcelerator Titanium Kitchensink. You can find this in kitchensink. Path : kitchensinl/resource/emaples/picker_android_spinner_text.js. Hope this will help. It's code to generate multi column picker in android.

```
  /*global Ti,Titanium,alert */
    var w = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
    var status = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        top: 5, left: 5, right: 5, height: 40, textAlign:'center'
    });
    w.add(status);

    function showStatus(s) {status.text = s;}

    var names = ['Joanie', 'Mickey', 'Jean-Pierre', 'Gustav', 'Raul', 'Mimi', 'Emily', 'Sandra', 'Carrie', 'Chachi'];
    var verbs = ['loves', 'likes', 'visits', 'loathes', 'waves to', 'babysits', 'accompanies', 'teaches', 'announces', 'supports', 'knows', 'high-fives'];

    var rows1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        rows1.push(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: names[i]}));
    }

    var rows2 = [];
    for (i = 0; i < verbs.length; i++) {
        rows2.push(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: verbs[i]}));
    }

    var rows3 = [];
    for (i = (names.length -1); i >=0; i--) {
        rows3.push(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: names[i]}));
    }

    var column1 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn( {
        rows: rows1, font: {fontSize: "12"}
    });
    var column2 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn( {
        rows: rows2, font: {fontSize: "12"}
    });
    var column3 = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn( {
        rows: rows3, font: {fontSize: "12"}
    });

    var picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
        useSpinner: true, visibleItems: 7,
        type : Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_PLAIN,
        top: 150, height: 200,
        columns: [ column1, column2, column3 ]
    });

    picker.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        showStatus(e.selectedValue[0] + " " + e.selectedValue[1] + " " + e.selectedValue[2]);
    });

    w.add(picker);
    var btnSelect = Ti.UI.createButton({
        left: 5, height: 40, top: 50, width: 150,
        title: 'Select idxs 2/4/6'
    });
    btnSelect.addEventListener('click', function() {
        picker.setSelectedRow(0, 2);
        picker.setSelectedRow(1, 4);
        picker.setSelectedRow(2, 6);
    });
    w.add(btnSelect);

    var btnAdd = Ti.UI.createButton({
        left: 165, height: 40, top: 50, width: 150,
        title: 'Add "Manny"'
    });
    btnAdd.addEventListener('click', function() {
        picker.columns[0].addRow(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: 'Manny'}));
        picker.columns[2].addRow(Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title: 'Manny'}));
        showStatus('"Manny" added to columns 0 & 2');
    });
    w.add(btnAdd);

    var btnRemove = Ti.UI.createButton({
        left: 5, height: 40, top: 100, width: 150,
        title: 'Remove all idx 3'
    });
    btnRemove.addEventListener('click', function() {
        picker.columns[0].removeRow( picker.columns[0].rows[3] );
        picker.columns[1].removeRow( picker.columns[1].rows[3] );
        picker.columns[2].removeRow( picker.columns[2].rows[3] );
        showStatus("value at index 3 of each col. removed");
    });
    w.add(btnRemove);

    var btnCheckSelection = Ti.UI.createButton({
        left: 165, height: 40, top: 100, width: 150,
        title: 'Check sel.'
    });
    btnCheckSelection.addEventListener('click', function() {
        showStatus(picker.getSelectedRow(0).title + ' ' + picker.getSelectedRow(1).title + ' ' + picker.getSelectedRow(2).title);
        var color = status.backgroundColor || w.backgroundColor || "black";
        status.backgroundColor = 'red';
        setTimeout(function(){status.backgroundColor=color;},1000);
    });
    w.add(btnCheckSelection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try https://gist.github.com/981250

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer using check boxes. Here is a discussion on this issue. [Stack-overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548038/create-a-checkbox-in-titanium)